# yellow screen issue with Dell Latitude 5498

Tags: display, dell-latitude

I have newest Latitude 5490 with 8th gen i7 and 16gb of RAM.

The screen of my laptop is little bit yellowish in comparison to my previous laptop (Latitude 5480). 
I have updated all the drivers and tried all the conventional methods available on YouTube
like :

```
setting different RGB in color management I have tried selecting sRGB2.1 profile.
changing color setting in Intel Graphic control like contrast , hue options.
```

but none worked.

can anyone help me please.

Comment: Welcome to superuser.com! In case you find an answer to help solve a problem don't forget to click either the grey ☑ or the up-pointing arrow/triangle to the left of the text.

Answer (score 0):

First note this:

1. There is no such thing as a perfectly calibrated display.
2. It is not easy to fine tune a display by hand (without tools).

But: There are descriptions online that help you hand-tune the display as close as is possible by hand. (google e.g. ["calibrate display"](https://www.google.se/search?q=calibrate%20display))

For best results; you need to teach yourself the basic color theory. 
One starting point for understanding the basics is the Tutorials at http://cambridgeincolour.com/

To get it as good as possible, you need hardware similar to:

- X-Rite i1Display
- X-Rite/Pantone ColorMunki
- Datacolor Spyder
- Pantone huey Pro (old, discontinued)

... or any (better) variant of them. Even the 100 €/$/£ -versions are quite capable for single screen calibration.

*Note: If you use Linux you need one that is supported by "Argyll" - 'the' calibration software.*

*Note: check your hardware, e.g. some laptops comes with 6-bit-per-channel displays.*

Comment: This assumes your hardware is working correctly.

Comment: This is the "right" way to do it, especially if you are doing graphics work and want accurate colors that match the printout.  However, calibration might be more than you need if you are just bothered that the screen has a yellowish cast.  A little supplementary information: (cont'd)

Comment: 1) That might be on purpose to reduce blue light, which is hard on your eyes.  Hunt for anything that indicates that, or an option to disable it. 2) I'm not familiar with the options built into the laptop, but at least many external displays have a menu of color profiles tailored to different kinds of material. 3) The OS often has a crude utility built-in to tweak the color manually. 4) If the OS has a gamma adjustment, you can use online patterns like available [here](http://www.lagom.nl/lcd-test/).

Comment: The answer hints on reading up on color theory, you don't need much of it to get to grips with how you need to adjust any color dials to get the effect you're after. I Highly recommend doing the reading - you will understand much of the internals of color in general, and digital color especially.  Check the Tutorials at http://cambridgeincolour.com/